# Intersection of a number on string using underscore library

Tags: node.js, underscore.js

I have two inputs one is this.

```
Data1: 1
Data 2: [1]
```

But if i use ._ like this.

> _.intersection(data2,data1)

It is giving me result like this.

```
Intersection: []
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [.intersection](https://underscorejs.org/#intersection) function seems to require array as parameters, you are passing first value as a number, try passing as array like:

```
...
data1 = 1;
data2 = [1];
_.intersection(data2,[data1]);
...
```

Comment: Its not working.

Comment: works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/g0947om1/

Comment: Is it possible to use some also with this? If I use some it is producing false. fiddle is attached I am expecting true http://jsfiddle.net/mh6r8t5o/ The reason is that i want to use intersection in if statement

Comment: @xxoyx `_.some` and `_.intersection` are very different functions. What is your ultimate goal here? I mean, in plain English? Are you trying to find elements in an array that meet a particular condition? Why are you trying to do that?